# mySQL group two INNER JOINs

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I basically want to join the result of two INNER JOINs.

On this scheme I want to get the **three arrows results combined**.

[image]

I've tried INNER / LEFT combinations but it doesn't do the trick.

I think a nested request could be the solution but how ?

Thanks

Comment: @Akina this would only give the center arrow on the diagram

Comment: Unclear... provide this as reproduceable sample (post CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO and desired output).

Comment: Do you need the contents of all three tables? Or just the contents of table1 where there is a matching row in either table2 or table3? Also, are the joins ever 1:many?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually simple : `UNION`

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM 
(SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = i.client_id
UNION
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1 t1 JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.client_id) as q1
;
```

Comment: A `UNION` works but can have a large overhead in removing duplicates. `UNION ALL` doesn't have that overhead and it CAN be more efficient to do `T1 join T2` `UNION ALL` `T1 join T3 left join T2 WHERE t2.id IS NULL` simply to avoid the overhead. In that case, @akina's answer is probably even more efficient still. I do not recommend you use this UNION approach, even though it is Functionally correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use logic to express the condition `T1.id exists in T2 or T3` more directly, and certainly avoid use of `DISTINCT` or `UNION`.

Options could be to use `EXISTS` directly *(As this is immure to the possibility of duplication cause by 1:many joins)*...

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM
  table1  t1
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.t1_id = t1.id)
  OR
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table3 t3 WHERE t3.t1_id = t1.id)
```

Or to `LEFT JOIN` twice and then exclude unwanted rows.  *(This assumes that the joins are never 1:many, which would introduce duplication, and the unwanted need for a `DISTINCT`.)*

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM
  table1  t1
LEFT JOIN
  table2  t2
    ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
LEFT JOIN
  table3  t3
    ON t1.id = t3.t1_id
WHERE
  t2.t1_id IS NOT NULL
  OR
  t3.t1_id IS NOT NULL
```